# Significance of generator attribute in @GeneratedValue annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="myseq") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="myseq",sequenceName="MY_SEQ") 
private long id;
```

What is the significance of `generator="myseq"` in annotation `@GeneratedValue` and `name="myseq"` in `@SequenceGenerator`. Is it good practise to use the same generator name for all the entities or should I give different name for each entity currently I have different sequence for each entity, please advice

Comment: you can use the same sequence for every entity as they are persisted in different tables in db. Also, if you are not looking for a custom numbering, you can use any of the in built sequence generators. however they do not guarantee that the sequence will be contiguous all the time.

Comment: But we already have different sequence for each entity in production, i just want to check what the significance of the attribute `generator="myseq"`. Is it like hibernate creates a new instance of some sort of service class which handle the id generation

Comment: If its so in production, there must be some reason. You should probably talk to someone who wrote it, if you can..

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question can be read from javadoc to [@SequenceGenerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html):

> Defines a primary key generator that may be referenced by name when a generator element is specified for the GeneratedValue annotation. A sequence generator may be specified on the entity class or on the primary key field or property. **The scope of the generator name is global** to the persistence unit (across all generator types).

I highlighted the important thing that **The scope of the generator name is global** to the persistence unit - this is defined by the specification and therefore you **cannot** define multiple generators with the **same name**. However, you may reuse already defined generator for multiple primary keys, if you put its name in `generator` field of `@GeneratedValue` annotation. In that case, I recommend to define @SequenceGenerator on an entity similarly to named queries, instead of defining it on a particular PK.

If you have separate sequences for each entity, you must give each of your generators a different name. You must then use this name in `@GeneratedValue`. If you don't, a default generator would be used, which is completely different from the one defined by any `@SequenceGenerator`. This is how it is, even though I would prefer that instead of default generator, the generator define together with the primary key field and `@GeneratedValue` annotation would be used. Java EE API is only coming close to being ideal, but is still not there yet...

To illustrate, following code would use default sequence generator, which is created by hibernate automatically if allowed.:

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)  // generator is missing, using default generator
  @SequenceGenerator(name="myseq", sequenceName="MY_SEQ") // name is required for generator, but it is not used with @GeneratedValue on this field
  private Long id;
}
```

On the other hand, you may define your generator and use it to generate PK values also on entity class:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="myseq", sequenceName="MY_SEQ") // name is required for generator, it is referenced by generator field in @GeneratedValue below
public class Entity {
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="myseq")  // generator myseq defined above is used
  private Long id;
}
```

You may even put the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation on a different entity, it does not make any difference, provided that you still reference it by its name in generator field of `@GeneratedValue`.

Answer (score 2):

[`@SequenceGenerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) defines the generator to be used for generating entity's primary keys.

Its `name` attribute gives it a name to reference it by in the [`@GeneratedValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) annotation. The `sequenceName` parameter represents the name of the sequence in the actual database. So in this case Hibernate will look for sequence called `MY_SEQ` in your database.

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="myseq", sequenceName="MY_SEQ")
```

Next you have `@GeneratedValue`. You specify the strategy to be used for the PK generation (sequence, table, etc.) and the generator (referenced by name you specified in the definition of sequence generator above).

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="myseq")
```

So to answer your question the `name`/`generator` parameters of these annotations are used to name and reference the generator which should be used for generating PKs.

Answer (score -1):

It calls the MY_SEQ sequence which puts the value of 'long id' as MY_SEQ + 1